# Remove password field from Django

Tags: django

I want to register in Django with a phone number and only get a phone number from the user

I don't even want to get a password from the user

That's why I decided to remove the password field from the custom user model(password=None)

But with this method, I cannot enter the admin panel in Django with created super user

It asks me for a password to enter the admin panel in Django

How can I enter the admin panel?

Code:

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def _create_user(self, name, phone_number, **extra_fields):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError("You have not provided a valid phone number")
    
    user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, name=name, **extra_fields)
    user.set_unusable_password()
    user.save(using=self._db)

    return user

def create_user(self, name=None, phone_number=None,  **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(name, phone_number,  **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, name=None, phone_number=None,  **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    return self._create_user(name, phone_number, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    password = None
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 25,blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: You are better off NOT removing the password field.  Just change your auth logic so that the user doesn't require a password to authenticate.  (But then you need to authenticate users some other way ... unless you and your users live in a world of "butterflies and zebras and moonbeams" where nobody pretends to be someone else.)

Comment: dont remove it, just generate some random password for users and implement phone pased auth